# Testing Spring Webflow Action Classes

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-webflow, easymock

I am writing test case for my webflow using `org.springframework.webflow.test.execution.AbstractXmlFlowExecutionTests`

```
public class MyFlowExecutionTests extends AbstractXmlFlowExecutionTests {
}
```

In some cases my logic is simple, So I invoke my service layer directly from the Spring webflow.
In some cases I use an extenstion of  org.springframework.webflow.action.MultiAction classes and I invoke my service layer from the action classes.

In the first scenario, wrting test case is straight forward. In the second scenario, I found it really complex to write the test cases using org.springframework.webflow.test.execution.AbstractXmlFlowExecutionTests for the Action class.
In the first scenario, I can mock all the service classes used from my flow. In the second scenario, using easy mock class extension, I can mock the action class. But then I need to mock the service layers used inside, which I think mock can't handle that well.

I am now thinking of somehow moving the Action class code to Spring EL. Or Anybody have a better idea for testing the action class code along with webflow code?

Comment: For the moment  I am actually moving my action class code to EL. But even in the  examples bundled with Spring framework, they don't have any examples using action classes. Initially when I started learning SWF, I was more comfortable using Action class (So that I can write Java Code) than using Spring EL.. Thanks

Comment: It wouldn't be my preference to move lots of logic to an expression language that I can't unit test... that's hiding your problem not solving it. Can you be a bit more specific about what "mock can't handle that well"? My first thought is that you are testing multiple methods/classes at once, and mock objects are exactly the tool for fixing that problem. (I haven't used the spring web flow stuff, just mocks and testing for lots of other stuff, so expand a bit with the details there...)

Comment: The actual logic or service call is encapsulated in a method and can be tested separately. So it is not actually not creating any problem. It is mostly invoking service layers. As such, It is not a unit testing issue but a web-flow testing issue when action classes are involved.